# Mean of a random variable from a reservation value to infinity

Tags: integration, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, means

say $a$ is a random variable from an $F(.)$ distribution and $\tilde{a} = E(a|a>a^r)$

I was wondering which law allows us to write the following :
$$\tilde{a}= \frac{\int_{a^r}^\infty adF(a)}{1-F(a^r)} $$

Do you have any idea? Thank you

Comment: What is $F(a\mid a>a^r)$?

Comment: @Patricio I don't know where you are leading me with this hint but what I tried to use in first hand is the fact that : $P(A|B) = \frac{P(AnB)}{P(B)}$, then $F(a|a>a^r) = \frac{P(a, a^r<a<\infty)}{P(a>a^r)}$. But not sure is the good method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume the reservation value $a^r$ is a constant. Note that
$$\int_{a^r}^\infty \tilde adF(\tilde a)=E[a{\bf1}_{a>a^r}]\
\\=E[E[a{\bf1}_{a>a^r}|{\bf1}_{a>a^r}]]\quad \text{(LIE)}\\
=E[a{\bf1}_{a>a^r}|{\bf1}_{a>a^r}=1]P({\bf1}_{a>a^r}=1)+\underbrace{E[a{\bf1}_{a>a^r}|{\bf1}_{a>a^r}=0]}_{=0}P({\bf1}_{a>a^r}=0)\\
=E[a|a>a^r]P(a>a^r)\\
=E[a|a>a^r](1-F(a^r)),$$

and rearranging gets you the result.

Comment: So it is the same  as $P(a|a>a^r) =\frac{P(a,a>a^r)}{P(a>a^r)}$ with $P(a,a>a^r)=\int_{a^r}^\infty adF(a)$?

Comment: I am not sure what that even means. Remember $a$ is a random variable. Are you referring to the conditional CDF $F(a^*|a>a^r)$, which is $P(a\leq a^*|a>a^r)$ for some constant $a^*$?

Comment: you are right I am combining two different definition. What I am meant is that this formula is the same as the conditional expectation one but applied to a random variable. no?

Comment: I guess you could write it as $E[a|a>a^r]=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \tilde a dF(\tilde a| a>a^r)$ and work out $F(\tilde a|a>a^r)=P(a^r<a\leq \tilde a)/P( a>a^r)$; but I think this requires some delicate handling for incorporating into the integral.

Comment: For me, LIE is cleanest